# mod rewrite expression in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this regular expression for mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(fr|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([x]+([a-z]+))/([y]+([a-z]+))/([z]+([a-z]+))$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&sc=$4&ssc=$5&sssc=$6 [L]
```

But in case of link: `http://example.com/4564/fr/gdgfdgbgdfgd/xfirst/ysecond/zthird`

I have these values:

```
start=4564
lang=fr
cat=gdgfdgbgdfgd
sc=xfirst
ssc=first
sssc=ysecond
```

So problem in: ssc и sssc.

I've changed to:

```
sc - a
ssc - b
sssc - c
```

but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is

```
start=4564
lang=fr
cat=gdgfdgbgdfgd
sc=xfirst
ssc=ysecond
sssc=zthird
```

then remove the captures after `[x]+`, `[y]+`, `[z]+`. So the rule would be

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(fr|ru|en)/([a-z]+|[0-9]+)/([x]+[a-z]+)/([y]+[a-z]+)/([z]+[a-z]+)$ /index.php?start=$1&lang=$2&cat=$3&sc=$4&ssc=$5&sssc=$6 [L]
```